# Application crashes when the clipboard access on Windows 10

Tags: windows, vb.net, crash, clipboard

The application was written in VB.net few year ago and the application have too meany background process but never had crashes before this. As my knowledge, this crashing problem happens after the latest windows 10 update. Visual Studio doesn't give any exception code. I have found the error line using `WinDbg` The error is sitting on this line `My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList`

can anyone suggest me the reason to happening this or a solution to fix this.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        'Get Clipboard Type
        Select Case True
            Case My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList
                ClipType = "File(s)"
            Case My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage
                ClipType = "Image"
            Case My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsAudio
                ClipType = "Audio"
            Case My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsText
                ClipType = "Text"
            Case Else
                ClipType = "Unknown"
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Dump Result:

```
MethodDesc:   00007ffb84ed5d38
Method Name:  MYAPP.MainWindow.Timer1_Tick(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
Class:        00007ffb84ecfeb0
MethodTable:  00007ffb84ed68a0
mdToken:      0000000006000895
Module:       00007ffb84d34148
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ffb85201460
Transparency: Critical
Source file:  D:\Project\~\MainWindow.vb @ 652

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 37

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on INT-PC-110

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 739

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 204

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : CLR.Engine
    Value: CLR

    Key  : CLR.Version
    Value: 4.0.30319.0

    Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
    Value: 679321

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 230


COMMENT:  Dump created by DbgHost. Second_Chance_Exception_C0000409
```

Comment: It works for me. No exceptions.

Comment: @JQSOFT It works when isolate the code, but not in the project.

Comment: Then we need to see more code mate.

Comment: [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener).